# Image is not selecting from gallery android studio java

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-image, android-gallery, startactivityforresult

I want to select image from phone gallery but when i click on image the app returns to main activity without updating image. currently i created the code in fragment. I wrote the code correctly but it is not working. i checked this similar code on another activity and it is working there fine. Here is the code. please figure out where i am doing mistake.

Java

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<FriendsModel> list;
    FragmentProfileBinding binding;


    public ProfileFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FragmentProfileBinding binding = FragmentProfileBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new FriendsModel(R.drawable.profile2));
        list.add(new FriendsModel(R.drawable.profile3));
        list.add(new FriendsModel(R.drawable.profile4));
        list.add(new FriendsModel(R.drawable.profile2));
        list.add(new FriendsModel(R.drawable.profile3));


        FriendsAdapter adapter = new FriendsAdapter(list, getContext());


        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        binding.friendsRV.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        binding.friendsRV.setAdapter(adapter);


        binding.changeCoverPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); // this will open gallery
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 11);

            }
        });
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (data.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            binding.coverImage.setImageURI(uri);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all check the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your Manifest. Then if you're targeting API 29 or higher try this code:

```
void openImageChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
}

public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                    // Get the url from data
                    final Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    if (null != selectedImageUri) {
                        // Get the path from the Uri
                        String path = getPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Image Path : " + path);
                        // Set the image in ImageView
                        findViewById(R.id.imgView).post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView)).setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

}

/* Get the real path from the URI */
public String getPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String res = null;
    String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        res = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return res;
}
```

And in this way you can get a Real path as well in case you need it.